# The selected file path is not a file

Tags: java, android

FilePath.java

```
 public class FilePath {

   public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
    String realPath;
    // SDK < API11
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        realPath = FilePath.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        realPath = FilePath.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
    else {
        realPath = FilePath.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
    }
    return realPath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = 0;
    String result = "";
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            // This is for checking Main Memory
            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                if (split.length > 1) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                } else {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                }
                // This is for checking SD Card
            } else {
                return "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
            }

        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            String fileName = getFilePath(context, uri);
            if (fileName != null) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
            }

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
 }
```

i have written code for upload all type of file on server, i need to select file path for uploading, it gives file path, which is not file, how to get file? i have try lot of code not work, how can i get file? please help me.
selected file path is /storage/emulated/0/Download/flag.png and this is not a file when check isfile() function, then print message this is not a file,

Comment: make sure you add necessary permissions and paths in xml

Comment: yes i have all ready add all permission

Comment: i don't know which is missing

Comment: what about provider? you should add one in your manifest if you haven't yet. check out this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider" />
        </provider>

Comment: Then I have no idea what could be wrong, sorry

Comment: Note that your code will fail for all Android Q and higher devices, and it will fail for lots of users of lots of other devices and apps. **Do not use this code**. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: can you share any example for it, thanks in advance